# Most as an adverb: before or after the main verb?

Tags: adverbs

Is it acceptable to place "most" before the main verb like the sentence below?

> I will remember you for being strong but I will most remember you for being kind.

Answer (score 1):

No - it's not acceptable to place 'most' before a verb. You need the adverbial form: **mostly**.

```
"I will mostly remember you..."
```

The sentence sounds a little awkward because of the repeated *I will remember you for". So it might be more idiomatic say, "... but I will particularly remember your kindness".

[This page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/most-the-most-mostly) has many examples of the use of 'most' and 'mostly'.